# What board should I ask for Software / Framework / Website suggestions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question and I don't know what Stack Exchange to put it on.

**My question is,** Does anyone have a suggestion for a website that will host audio files that I can embed / stream on my website? There are a lot and I'm not sure what features are necessary.

I go to Stack Overflow because I'm a developer and I'm building this website. But I know that SO wasn't built for Software / Plugin / Services questions.

Where should I go? AND how would I know that? The Stack Overflow communities page is neat but doesn't help in this case.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com maybe, take care of their policies.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I didnt see that one.

Comment: And there were a proposal for [Website Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendations) but it was closed.

Comment: This one should work. I just didn't want to pollute the wrong community.

Comment: If you are going to post it on SoftwareRecs.SE, take a very long look at their [guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and read their help center as well.  You question, as posted here, is extremely vague and would not be acceptable there.  You need to be specific about what you need, and what you are looking for in terms of features or functionality.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for random *suggestions*, then you really are not going to find a site in the Stack Exchange network that will accept your question.

However, if you are looking for specific software/API recommendations to solve a specific problem, then you may find help at [Software Recommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help).  Before asking a question there, you need to understand that the site does not provide recommendations to vague/unspecific requests for suggestions.   To help write a question there, I strongly encourage you to look at:

- [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)
- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Effectively, they are looking for people to provide specific tools to meet specific requirements, just become a bulletin board of vague suggestions to unspecific problems.

---

If the extent of your question is exactly what you posted in the question body

> Does anyone have a suggestion for a website that will host audio files that I can embed / stream on my website? There are a lot and I'm not sure what features are necessary.

then this is definitely not on topic for SoftwareRecs.  You will need to try to narrow it down somehow.  What kinds of things are you looking for?  Even if you don't know what features exist, you should have some idea of what you need.  Think about things like:

- Do I have a price range?  Or am I looking for a free service?
- How much bandwidth do I expect to need every month?
- Is there a limit on my storage capacity.
- Any probably more....

I don't know all of the right questions to ask, but that should get you started.  If you need more help, then you can visit [Meta.SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/) to get some more specific guidance or visit chat and get additional feedback or suggestions.